# setBackgroundResource in Android Studio expects drawable, not int

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement some `ImageView` buttons programmatically, so I can sort them at runtime.

I use a layout resource called `image_bg` as background to the buttons in XML, as seen here in my `activity_main.xml`:

```
   <ImageView android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/a"
        android:background="@layout/image_bg"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
```

Attempting to set the background to layout/image_bg programmatically, I run into this error:

[image: img]

I can't manage to set the background to the layout file, no matter what combinations commands I use. I've searched extensively, and tried all manner of combinations of `getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.image_bg)`, and using `setBackground(R.layout.image_bg)` instead - but I've had no luck so far.

EDIT: ------------------------------------------------

After moving the image_bg.xml file to R.drawable as suggested, the syntax error was fixed, but the following error occurs during runtime:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{m.fugl/m.fugl.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006a
```

The content of image_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <solid android:color="#000000" />
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#776da8"/>
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
  <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
  </shape>
```

I've tried running gradlew clean, but it hasn't helped.

EDIT2---------------------------------------------------:

Attempted to change my image_bg.xml file into this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="#000000" />
  <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#776da8"/>
  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="3dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="3dp" android:topLeftRadius="3dp" android:topRightRadius="3dp" />
  <padding android:left="2dp" android:top="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp" />
  </shape>
```

I still recieve an error. The entire stack trace:

```
07-01 18:14:58.817      977-977/m.fugl E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: m.fugl, PID: 977
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{m.fugl/m.fugl.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006a
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2329)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006a
            at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1310)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:790)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:770)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:402)
            at android.view.View.setBackgroundResource(View.java:16105)
            at m.fugl.SoundButton.<init>(SoundButton.java:58)
            at m.fugl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:111)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2282)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:147)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1296)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

EDIT3---------------------------------:

Soundbutton is a class that holds an Imageview, a sound, and various methods used for playback of the sound. Here is its constructor:

```
SoundButton(int uri, Context context, int src, CharSequence text) {
        //Binder lyd og knap til constructor parametre
        globalUri = uri;
        globalContext = context;
        globalText = text;
        buttonId = new ImageView(context);

        createSoundForButton();

        buttonId.setImageResource(src);
        buttonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_bg);
        buttonId.setClickable(true);
        buttonId.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
        buttonId.setLongClickable(false);
        buttonId.setHovered(false);
        setButtonIsPlaying(false);
        setVisible(false);

        // Når der trykkes på knappen....
        buttonId.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                playOrPauseSound();
            }
        });

        buttonId.setLongClickable(true);

        buttonId.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(globalContext, view);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(SoundButton.this);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.popup_menu);
                popupMenu.show();
                buttonId.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                popupMenu.setOnDismissListener(new PopupMenu.OnDismissListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDismiss(PopupMenu menu) {
                        setButtonIsPlaying(false);
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem is supposedly on line 58 right at: 
    buttonId.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_bg);

EDIT4---------------------------------:
I found the answer. I copied the image_bg.xml file to the drawables folder from inside Android Studio, and that made it land in the drawable-large-mdpi folder, instead of the drawable folder. After copying image_bg.xml into the drawable folder it now works, because the compiler can find the xml file!

Comment: try putting image_bg in drawable folder and take is from there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the picture you posted, you are providing a value from `R.layout`, while it is waiting an int  from `R.drawable`.

`R.layout.image_bg` should be `R.drawable.image_bg`, and hopefully you put the `image_bg` in one of the drawable folders

Comment: I should have mentioned that image_bg is an xml layout file. When I put it in the drawable folder, it fixes the syntax error, but instead I get the following exception:

    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{m.fugl/m.fugl.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02006a

#0x7f02006a is a color-code in the .xml. I'm guessing it's because this is not the correct way to set a layout as background.

Comment: Post the content of the file

Comment: remove `android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"` from `<shape` and run it again

Comment: can you post the changes you made to the shape, and the whole stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: I have now posted the new image_bg.xml as changed upon your suggestion, and the entire stacktrace of the exception in Edit2

Comment: what is SoundButton? Can you post its constructor ?  I tried your shape on my phone and it is working

Comment: Thank you for all your help Blackbelt. I have posted EDIT3

Comment: I found the answer. I copied the image_bg.xml file to the drawables folder from inside Android Studio, and that made it land in the drawable-large-mdpi folder, instead of the drawable folder.

After copying image_bg.xml into the drawable folder it now works!

Answer (score 0):

> **Put image in drawable folder**

```
myImgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_bg);

myImgView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_bg));
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can't set layout as background**

You need to put the image in drawable folder and then use `getResources().getDrawable(R.layout.image_bg)`

and then

`setBackground(R.layout.image_bg)`